# Change CSS/formatting on specific page, but not pages in general?

Tags: formatting

How do I change the formatting on 
http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/voronoi-temperature-map/ 
so that (for example) the map's nearly flush with the bottom of the menubar?

I don't want to edit page.php, since that'll change all pages, not just this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After creating the specific CSS you need to format the page how you like, you could:

1. Create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) with the CSS and assign the template this page.
2. Create a page-{slug}.php file with the CSS, where {slug} is the page slug for this page (most likely the filename should be page-voronoi-temperature-map.php).
3. Create a page-{ID}.php file, where if the page ID is 6, WordPress will look to use page-6.php.

These three options were mentioned in the Codex, under [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display). By using any of these 3 options, you can alter the layout for this page without affecting all the rest of your pages.

Comment: Thanks! page.php itself says "If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.", but that didn't seem right, since loop-page.php displays all posts, and not a single page.

Answer (score 12):

If you look at the page source, you'll see that `<body>` has been given a class `page-id-1199`. You can use that in your stylesheet to specify styles for that page alone.

```
.page-id-1199 #map { /* custom styles */ }
```